# Socket API calling but not getting result on console SOCKET.IO angular

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io

I can see the message on Chrome Network tab (WS) but its not subscribing at my
`app.compoenent.ts`.

Socket connection screenshot
[image: Socket at chrome debugger]

socket.service.ts

```
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

    private socket: Socket
    constructor() {
        this.socket = new Socket({
          url: environment.socketUrl, options: {
              secure: false,
              transports: ['websocket'],
              upgrade: false,
          }
        });
      }
    receiveMessage() {
        console.log("function hit")
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            this.socket.on("message", (message) => {                
                observer.next(message);
            });
        });
      }
```

app.component.ts

```
  this._socketService.receiveMessage().subscribe( (data) => {
    console.log(data);    
  });
```

At console I can see the socket function being called but its not working.
[image: socket console]

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: Yes it is. Am still unable to run

Comment: Could this be a timing issue maybe? What happens if you pit a console inside the on message callback?

Comment: `this.socket.on("message", (message) => { ` this line get triggers but the it doesn't respond anything. I tried adding some console log after that line and before ` observer.next(message);`. but doesn't trigger.

Comment: What happens when you put the this.socket.on("message", (message) => { callback inside your constructor (with a console in there?)?

Comment: Also.. there is a namespace error in your ws console..

Comment: what happens on the server? were you able to create a valid connection and see it on the server?

Comment: Thank you guys for the comment. The problem was with the server port 3000. There were some redirection which causes the socket closes and give bad request error message. This error was identified by a senior developer and the angular code seems okay. After creating different port and create socket on that port it was working fine with my code.